# How to use shebang in windows for Python?

Tags: python, windows, shebang, windows-11, pylauncher

Code

```
#! C:\Python310\python.exe
import os
import sys
print(f"PY_PYTHON={os.getenv('PY_PYTHON')}")
print(f"{sys.version=}")
print(f"Shebang : '{open(__file__).read().splitlines()[0]}'")
cmd = 'py -0p'
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
cmd = f'file {__file__}'
print(cmd)
os.system(cmd)
```

Output:

```
λ py t9.py
PY_PYTHON=None
sys.version='3.11.0a7 (main, Apr  5 2022, 21:27:39) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]'
Shebang : '#! C:\Python310\python.exe'
py -0p
 -V:3.11 *        C:\Python311\python.exe
 -V:3.10          C:\Python310\python.exe
 -V:3.9           C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
file C:\Users\smart\Desktop\budhubot\budhubot\t9.py
C:\Users\smart\Desktop\budhubot\budhubot\t9.py: a  C:\Python310\python.exe script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminator
```

Tried forward slash too.

Edit:
Without space
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Shebangs aren't a Windows thing.

On Windows, it must rely on a third-party software: bash, cygwin, python launcher, etc. So you'll find most information about its support in these third-party softwares' documentation.

But first thing, I would try to remove the space between `#!` and the interpreter's full path. Shebang and interpreter aren't separated by a space usually.

```
#!C:\Python310\python.exe
```

Comment: Tried. edited qn. FYI, Space used in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#:~:text=%23!%20%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fpython,starting%20with%20%2Fusr.)

Comment: Doc don't show a SINGLE example of shebang + windows path... Only Unix portable virtual commands. Maybe it's the problem? Or maybe search in PyLauncher's support?

Comment: syntax https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/#:~:text=%23!%20interpreter%20%5Boptional-arg,the%20following%20rules%3A

Comment: Yeah, but still no examples of shebangs with Windows paths... Look at the other answer, maybe a clue. It seems that it doesn't work "out-of-the-box".

Comment: examples are only derived from the syntax. FYI, I wrote the other answer.

Comment: @SmartManoj Oh, right, my bad, for the other answer. What I meant is that documentation, despite being mostly for Windows, lacks examples for Windows and shows only Unix paths - while PyLauncher being near irrelevant on Linux, since bash & other shells support shebangs natively.

Answer (score 0):

Add py.ini file in the `py.exe` location.

```
[commands]
py311="C:\Python311\python.exe"6
py310="C:\Python310\python.exe"6
py39="C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"6
```

Note the last char (use any); Without this, pylauncher not works. (2nd outptut). Probably a bug. [Repo](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/src/master/)

[image]

Edit:

**Shebangs are not working with `py -u`**